# Hide any first element that contains image

Tags: jquery, html, image, hide

Since the `post-body` contains number of elements, from link to div, I want to hide only the "first" child element that has image in it.

```
<div class="post-body">
  <div class="separator"><img/></div>
</div>
```

There's only one `.post-body` and I don't want to hide the `.post-body`, but the first element in `.post-body` that contains `img`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (the button is used to show before and after):

```js
function myFunction()
{
    $('.post-body img:first').parent().hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-body">
   <div class="separator">
      <div class="separator">First div inside post-body</div>
      <div class="separator"><img src=""/>Second div inside post-body</div>
      <div class="separator">Third div inside post-body</div>
      <div class="separator"><img src=""/>Fourth div inside post-body</div>
   </div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click to hide" />
```

Comment: I dont want to hide the `.post-body`, but the first element that contains image in `.post-body`

Comment: @Biyan This hides the first parent container to contain an image. I updated my answer to show how it works. Notice there are now `4 divs` inside another `div` which is inside the `.post-body div`. Only the parent of the first image gets deleted, others remain. Run the snippet above. Let me know if that is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:has()` selector to select all children of `.post-body` that have an image inside, then use the `:first` selector to pick the first one in the list:

```js
function hide() {
  $('.post-body :has(img):first').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="hide()" value="hide first image" />
<div class="post-body">
  <div class="separator">no image</div>
  <a><img/>first image</a>
  <p><img/>second image</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are a number of matching elements, jQuery returns an array of those as a result of the selector. So, you should be able to select the first element by array's index, and hide its parent `.post-body`:

```
$($(".post-body img")[0]).parent(".post-body").hide()
```